# How to fix Symmetric NAT Router Router?

Tags: networking, router, firewall, port-forwarding, nat

I am trying to host game on game ranger , it gives me the following message:

Your internet connection is behind a Symmetric NAT Modem/Router that will prevent you from hosting all games, and from joining peer-peer games.

[image]

Found the following description on GameRanger site:
 [image]

This is what my router's page looks like :
 [image]

The only thing that works is : https://www.hideallip.com/
I tried their 3 days trial and it made this issue vanish! I had been told by my service provided that the issue can only be fixed if I buy static IP.

But the fact that this piece of software is capable of solving this issue I don't think I need static IP.

Comment: Is your ISP dynamic IP changing frequently ?  My own IP changes once every 18 months or so.  I change setups when it changes. You can also use DynDNS.com to set up the appearance of a static IP.

Comment: You don’t need a static IP. But you do need to configure port forwarding. What have you done to do so? It doesn’t say use a DMZ. It says port forwarding. In your case it looks to be called port triggering. Or, as suggested, you can enable uPNP. What configurations have you tried to solve this problem? There is tons of information online about configuring port forwarding.

Comment: @John I think my IP changes when I restart computer or may be in several hours or days. But definitely not as long months.

Comment: @Appleoddity I several things based on youtube videos. Such as this one :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0dgndU0lYys

Comment: @Appleoddity and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R8lS7YqErtA

Comment: Try DynDNS.  It works fine - we have used it at clients

Comment: I don’t want to watch YouTube videos to figure out what you tried to do. I want you to [edit] your post with specific details about what you have configured to try to make this work. Port forwarding is simple. Other problems may exist, but it makes sense to first confirm you configured port forwarding correctly. Your DMZ screenshot does not look correct.

Comment: @John I have not tried it yet. But even if it does, it's not free. If I have to use a paid service I could use hideallip it works.

Comment: DynDNS is not free, but not too pricey for one user.

Comment: @John everything is pricey when you convert USD into INR. :(